# Question about deterministic finite automaton and accepting states

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language, finite-automata

For $n \in \mathbb N$, an "$n-$DFA" is an automaton with exactly $n$ accepting states.

Let $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$. Prove that the set of the languages that can be accepted by "$1-$DFA" is a subset of the set of the languages that can be accepted by "$2-$DFA".

I have no idea what to do with this question. Frankly, I thought of a counter example of $ L_1 =\varnothing $ but I've been told that this language has a finite-automaton with $2$ accepting-states, is it possible?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: For the empty language use three states, $q_0,q_1$, and $q_2$. For $k=0,1,2$ and $i=0,1$ you have transitions $q_k\overset{i}q_k$; $q_0$ iw the initial state, and $q_1$ and $q_2$ are accepting states.

Answer (score 4):

It's a trick answer: your states don't have to form a connected graph. (i.e. the states don't all have to be reachable from the start state).

So take any 1-DFA, add an accepting state that isn't connected to anything, and, hey, it's a 2-DFA.